# InvalidMappingException Hibernate mapping file...anybody can you give resolution

Tags: hibernate

**My mapping file is**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping >

<class name="com.myapp.companypojo.Company" table="COMPANY">
        <property column="COMPANYNAME" length="25" name="companyName" not-null="false" type="java.lang.String"/>
        <property column="LOCATION" length="25" name="location" not-null="false" type="java.lang.String"/>
        <property column="NOOFEMPLOYESS" length="25" name="totalEmployees" type="java.lang.String"/>
        <property column="LOB" length="25" name="lineOfBusiness" type="java.lang.String"/>

</class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

After validating the mapping file from IDE it throw an below error  and console I got `InvalidMappingException`...anybody can u give resolution??

> XML validation started.
>
> Checking
>   file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/Administrator/My%20Documents/NetBeansProjects/CMCApp/src/java/com/myapp/companypojo/Company.hbm.xml...
>   The content of element type "class" must match
>   "(meta*,subselect?,cache?,synchronize*,comment?,tuplizer*,(id|composite-id),discriminator?,natural-id?,(version|timestamp)?,(property|many-to-one|one-to-one|component|dynamic-component|properties|any|map|set|list|bag|idbag|array|primitive-array)*,((join*,subclass*)|joined-subclass*|union-subclass*),loader?,sql-insert?,sql-update?,sql-delete?,filter*,resultset*,(query|sql-query)*)".
>   [12]  XML validation finished.
>
> INFO: Launching GlassFish on Apache Felix OSGi platform Welcome to
>   Felix.
>   ================= INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.core.kernel [73] INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.common.glassfish-mbeanserver [12]
>   INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.common.common-util [90] INFO:
>   Started bundle GlassFish-Application-Common-Module [13] INFO:
>   APIClassLoader = Class Loader for Bundle
>   [GlassFish-Application-Common-Module [13] ] INFO: registering service
>   = org.apache.felix.framework.StartLevelImpl@16dadf9, contract = org.osgi.service.startlevel.StartLevel, name = null INFO: registering
>   service = org.apache.felix.framework.PackageAdminImpl@290fbc, contract
>   = org.osgi.service.packageadmin.PackageAdmin, name = null no resource bundle found for version, using default GlassFish version INFO:
>   Started bundle org.glassfish.branding.branding [92] INFO:
>   [Thread[GlassFish Kernel Main Thread,5,main]] started INFO: Started
>   bundle org.glassfish.admin.config-api [81] INFO: Started bundle
>   org.glassfish.common.internal-api [31] INFO: Started bundle
>   org.glassfish.deployment.deployment-common [103] INFO: Started bundle
>   org.glassfish.deployment.deployment-autodeploy [38] INFO: Started
>   bundle org.glassfish.registration.glassfish-registration [79] INFO:
>   Started bundle org.glassfish.flashlight.flashlight-framework [106]
>   INFO: Listening on port 8080 INFO: Network listener http-listener-2 on
>   port 8181 disabled per domain.xml INFO: Listening on port 4848 INFO:
>   Started bundle org.glassfish.common.container-common [34] INFO: The
>   Admin Console is already installed, but not yet loaded. INFO: Started
>   bundle org.glassfish.connectors.gf-connectors-connector [76] INFO:
>   Started bundle org.glassfish.security.security [63] INFO: Started
>   bundle org.glassfish.scripting.gf-jruby-connector [75] INFO: Started
>   bundle org.glassfish.persistence.jpa-connector [91] INFO: Started
>   bundle org.glassfish.web.gf-web-connector [120] INFO:
>   security.secmgroff INFO: Started bundle
>   org.glassfish.security.securitycommon [53] INFO: Security startup
>   service called INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.security.realms [23]
>   INFO: Security service(s) started successfully.... INFO: registering
>   service = org.glassfish.web.DirContextURLStreamHandlerService@179f36b,
>   contract = org.osgi.service.url.URLStreamHandlerService, name = null
>   INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.common.glassfish-naming [28] INFO:
>   Started bundle org.glassfish.web.web-glue [116] INFO: Total number of
>   available updates : 1 INFO: Number of available updates since Fri Nov
>   13 17:55:30 IST 2009 : 0 INFO: Started bundle
>   org.glassfish.common.glassfish-api [104] INFO: Started bundle
>   org.glassfish.connectors.connectors-runtime [37] INFO: Started bundle
>   org.glassfish.transaction.jta [68] INFO: Started JMXConnector,
>   JMXService URL =
>   service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://HP26258104442:8686/jmxrmi INFO: Created
>   HTTP listener http-listener-1 on port 8080 INFO: Created HTTP listener
>   admin-listener on port 4848 INFO: Created virtual server server INFO:
>   Created virtual server __asadmin INFO: Started bundle
>   org.glassfish.deployment.dol [22] INFO: Started bundle
>   org.glassfish.web.web-core [112] INFO: Dual registration of jndi
>   stream handler: factory already defined INFO: Unknown loader 116.0
>   class org.apache.felix.framework.searchpolicy.ContentClassLoader INFO:
>   Started bundle org.glassfish.web.jsf-connector [125] INFO: Started
>   bundle org.glassfish.web.jstl-connector [117] INFO: Using
>   com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplifiedDelegate
>   as the delegate INFO: Started bundle
>   org.glassfish.connectors.work-management [77] INFO: Started bundle
>   org.glassfish.common.glassfish-ee-api [48] INFO: Started bundle
>   org.glassfish.connectors.connectors-internal-api [30] INFO:
>   policy.loading INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.web.war-util [110]
>   INFO: Started bundle org.glassfish.security.websecurity [109] INFO:
>   Unknown loader
>   org.glassfish.internal.api.DelegatingClassLoader@1cbd4f7 class
>   org.glassfish.internal.api.DelegatingClassLoader INFO: Loading chain
>   catalog from
>   jar:file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/Administrator/My%20Documents/NetBeansProjects/MyStrutsApp/build/web/WEB-INF/lib/struts-core-1.3.8.jar!/org/apache/struts/chain/chain-config.xml
>   INFO: Tiles definition factory loaded for module ''. INFO: Loading
>   validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/validator-rules.xml' INFO:
>   Loading validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/validation.xml' INFO:
>   Loading application MyStrutsApp at /MyStrutsApp INFO: Loading
>   MyStrutsApp Application done is 11141 ms INFO: Unknown loader
>   org.glassfish.internal.api.DelegatingClassLoader@1cbd4f7 class
>   org.glassfish.internal.api.DelegatingClassLoader INFO: Loading chain
>   catalog from
>   jar:file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/Administrator/My%20Documents/NetBeansProjects/CMCApp/build/web/WEB-INF/lib/struts-core-1.3.8.jar!/org/apache/struts/chain/chain-config.xml
>   INFO: Tiles definition factory loaded for module ''. INFO: Loading
>   validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/validator-rules.xml' INFO:
>   Loading validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/validation.xml' INFO:
>   Loading application CMCApp at /CMCApp INFO: Loading CMCApp Application
>   done is 3109 ms INFO: Sun GlassFish Enterprise Server v3 Prelude
>   startup time : Felix(17750ms) startup services(17109ms) total(34859ms)
>   INFO: Unknown loader
>   org.glassfish.internal.api.DelegatingClassLoader@1cbd4f7 class
>   org.glassfish.internal.api.DelegatingClassLoader INFO: Loading chain
>   catalog from
>   jar:file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/Administrator/My%20Documents/NetBeansProjects/CMCApp/build/web/WEB-INF/lib/struts-core-1.3.8.jar!/org/apache/struts/chain/chain-config.xml
>   INFO: Tiles definition factory loaded for module ''. INFO: Loading
>   validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/validator-rules.xml' INFO:
>   Loading validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/validation.xml' INFO:
>   Loading application CMCApp at /CMCApp INFO: Deployment of CMCApp done
>   is 4406 ms INFO: Tiles definition factory found for request processor
>   ''. INFO: Hibernate 3.2.5 INFO: hibernate.properties not found INFO:
>   Bytecode provider name : cglib INFO: using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp
>   handling INFO: configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml INFO:
>   Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml INFO: Reading mappings from
>   resource : com/myapp/companypojo/Company.hbm.xml SEVERE: Error parsing
>   XML: XML InputStream(11) The content of element type "class" must
>   match
>   "(meta*,subselect?,cache?,synchronize*,comment?,tuplizer*,(id|composite-id),discriminator?,natural-id?,(version|timestamp)?,(property|many-to-one|one-to-one|component|dynamic-component|properties|any|map|set|list|bag|idbag|array|primitive-array)*,((join*,subclass*)|joined-subclass*|union-subclass*),loader?,sql-insert?,sql-update?,sql-delete?,filter*,resultset*,(query|sql-query)*)".
>   SEVERE: org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping
>   document from resource com/myapp/companypojo/Company.hbm.xml
>           at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:569)
>           at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:1587)
>           at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1555)
>           at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1534)
>           at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1508)
>           at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1428)
>           at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1414)
>           at com.myapp.hibernate.CompanyHibernateUtil.addCompanyDetails(CompanyHibernateUtil.java:33)
>           at com.myapp.struts.CompanyDetailsAction.execute(CompanyDetailsAction.java:43)
>           at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:425)
>           at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:228)
>           at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
>           at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.servletService(ApplicationFilterChain.java:431)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.preInvoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:462)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:139)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:186)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:719)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:657)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:96)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:98)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:187)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:719)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:657)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:651)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1030)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:142)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:719)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:657)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:651)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1030)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:325)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:242)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:180)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(DefaultProcessorTask.java:633)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProcessorTask.doProcess(DefaultProcessorTask.java:570)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProcessorTask.process(DefaultProcessorTask.java:827)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:152)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GlassfishProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(GlassfishProtocolChain.java:71)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:103)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:89)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:67)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:56)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.util.WorkerThreadImpl.processTask(WorkerThreadImpl.java:325)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.util.WorkerThreadImpl.run(WorkerThreadImpl.java:184)
>   Caused by: org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse
>   mapping document from invalid mapping
>           at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addInputStream(Configuration.java:502)
>           at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:566)
>           ... 47 more Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The content of element type "class" must match
>   "(meta*,subselect?,cache?,synchronize*,comment?,tuplizer*,(id|composite-id),discriminator?,natural-id?,(version|timestamp)?,(property|many-to-one|one-to-one|component|dynamic-component|properties|any|map|set|list|bag|idbag|array|primitive-array)*,((join*,subclass*)|joined-subclass*|union-subclass*),loader?,sql-insert?,sql-update?,sql-delete?,filter*,resultset*,(query|sql-query)*)".
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:236)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:172)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:382)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:316)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleEndElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:2048)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.endElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:932)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:719)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1685)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:368)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:834)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:148)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1242)
>           at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:465)
>           at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addInputStream(Configuration.java:499)
>           ... 48 more INFO: Unknown loader org.glassfish.internal.api.DelegatingClassLoader@1cbd4f7 class
>   org.glassfish.internal.api.DelegatingClassLoader INFO: Loading chain
>   catalog from
>   jar:file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/Administrator/My%20Documents/NetBeansProjects/CMCApp/build/web/WEB-INF/lib/struts-core-1.3.8.jar!/org/apache/struts/chain/chain-config.xml
>   INFO: Tiles definition factory loaded for module ''. INFO: Loading
>   validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/validator-rules.xml' INFO:
>   Loading validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/validation.xml' INFO:
>   Loading application CMCApp at /CMCApp INFO: Deployment of CMCApp done
>   is 3109 ms

Answer (score 1):

Go in your IDE (Eclipse, for instance), right click the xml file and press "Validate". It will tell you where you do not conform to the xml schema. (The exception means that)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the interesting part of the stacktrace:

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The
>   content of element type "class" must
>   match
>   "(meta,subselect?,cache?,synchronize*,comment?,tuplizer*,(id|composite-id),discriminator?,natural-id?,(version|timestamp)?,(property|many-to-one|one-to-one|component|dynamic-component|properties|any|map|set|list|bag|idbag|array|primitive-array),((join,subclass*)|joined-subclass*|union-subclass*),loader?,sql-insert?,sql-update?,sql-delete?,filter*,resultset*,(query|sql-query)*)"

It looks like at least the id or composite-id tag **must** be in the class mapping.  It looks as though the company name might be a good id, or you could have an auto-generated id if you expect there to be more than one company with the same name.  All the options are available here:
[Chapter 5: Basic O/R Mapping](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration)